# Когда нужно использовать Next JS

Tags: java, reactjs, spring-boot, frontend, nextjs

Всем привет! Изучаю реакт относительно недавно и сейчас делаю социальную сеть. Подскажите пожалуйста имеет ли смысл для соц сети подключать Next JS или это излишне? Стек фронт: React JS, Redux RTK, бек: Java Spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от задач, которые вы преследуете в разработке вашего проекта. Какая социальная сеть? Нужна ли адекватная SEO оптимизация в будущем? Какая нагрузка предполагается?

Что касается Next, то он предназначенный для разработки приложений, обладающих функционалом, выходящим за рамки SPA. Основным недостатком SPA являются проблемы с индексацией страниц таких приложений поисковыми роботами, что негативно влияет на SEO. Возможно сейчас ситуация ужел учше, чем во времена когда я разрабатывал SPA. Вам лучше заранее ознакомиться с этим моментом.

Как я понимаю, соц.сеть ваша будет выходить за рамки SPA, поэтому есть смысл использовать тот же Next, но опять же, все зависит от специфичности ваших задач с оглядкой на возможные недостатки Next'a.

Comment: спасибо за совет